# Using Limit on Delete SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I had this query

```
DELETE c FROM review_comments AS c 
LEFT JOIN users AS u 
ON u.user_id = c.user_id
WHERE c.comment = '{$comment}'
AND u.username = '{$user}'
LIMIT 1;
```

It did not work until I removed `LIMIT 1`;

It said:  `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 6`

Is this the incorrect usage of `LIMIT 1` in this instance? I had a same query without joining tables and `LIMIT 1` worked fine?

Comment: Even if the syntax allowed it, it's questionable logic.  If you want to delete a single record, you should be more specific about which record.

Comment: I think you should look into techniques for removing duplicate records, since this is what (if I understand correctly) you are essentially doing.

Comment: No my logic is not sound, it needs to be changed.  I need to grab the 'comment_id', not the 'comment' AND 'user who made it'.  It's a hack until I fix the bigger issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think LIMIT can be used with multi-table referenced DELETE statements in MySQL.